# Update xml file with ColdFusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion, xpath, coldfusion-9

I have an xml file that needs to updated. The user wants to be able to select the year and amount. What is the best way?

Thanks

```
<root>
<SGA>
<Year>2008</Year>
<Amt>940</Amt>
</SGA>
<SGA>
<Year>2009</Year>
<Amt>980</Amt>
</SGA>
<SGA>
<Year>2010</Year>
<Amt>1000</Amt>
</SGA>  
</root>
```

Comment: The user needs to update the file, but select the year and amount - I'm confused :| Can you please explain a little better?

Comment: For instance if the user wants to change the amount from 1000 to 2000 in the 2010 year tag.

Comment: XPath is a query language -- it cannot change an XML document. In order to produce a new XML document from an existing one you need some additional tool. XSLT is the language that was designed especially with the purpose of transforming one XML document into another. Ask this question in the xslt tag and you'll get an amazingly simple, short and powerful answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the <s>'contains' operator</s> (Alejandro points out that that's not a strict match) a match in XPath.  To execute XPath in Coldfusion, use the [xmlSearch function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_t-z_24.html) on an XML object. The normalize-space() function trims leading and trailing whitespace (fixing, for instance the CR in the 2010 year node).

Because the XPath is matching the year node directly, we use the '/..' to fetch the year node's parent.  This is if you wanted to operate on any of the other sibling nodes to year (for instance if there was also a "quantity" node or something).

```
<cfxml variable="foo">
<root>
<SGA>
<Year>2008</Year>
<Amt>940</Amt>
</SGA>
<SGA>
<Year>2009</Year>
<Amt>980</Amt>
</SGA>
<SGA>
<Year>2010
</Year>
<Amt>1000</Amt>
</SGA>  
</root>
</cfxml>


<cfset targetYear=" 2010">
<cfset newAmount=2000>

<cfdump var="#foo#">

<!--- returns an array of matching nodes. --->
<cfset bar = xmlSearch(foo,"/root/SGA/Year[normalize-space()='#trim(targetYear)#']/..")>

<cfdump var="#bar#">

<cfset bar[1].Amt.xmlText = newAmount>

<cfdump var="#foo#">
```

In a real application, you'd want to iterate over the results of the xmlSearch (bar in this case) as an array, as there exists the possibility to get 0 or more then 1 result.

Comment: Thanks, the contains function is what I needed.

Comment: @Edwars M Smith: `contains()` function is not a strict match like `/root/SGA[.='#targetYear#')]` or `/root/SGA[normalize-space()='#targetYear#')]`

Comment: @Alejandro - thank you - updated answer to reflect your corrections.